# How to link dependencies of library with plain signature of target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake 3.1+ project, where I use targets and link interfaces like that:

```
add_library(Core src/Core.cpp include/Core/Core.h)
target_include_directories(Core PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(Core PUBLIC Otherlib)
```

However, I also use a framework which provides macros using legacy CMake commands, as the plain signature of `target_link_libraries`:

```
# Call add_library and target_link_libraries plain singature
orocos_component(MyComponent src/MyComponent.cpp)

# Warning ! Policy CMP0023 is not set: Plain and keyword target_link_libraries
# signatures cannot be mixed. 
# target_link_libraries(MyComponent PRIVATE Core)

# The INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES, INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and other interface properties of Core are not used
# Cause error: Core/Core.h: No such file directory
target_link_libraries(MyComponent Core)
```

What are my options to make it work correctly ?
I can do something like:

```
target_include_directories(MyComponent
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:Core,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)
target_link_libraries(MyComponent
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:Core,INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES>
)
#etc...
```

However I have a lot of component and its rather a heavy solution. Is there something better to try? I do not want to set `CMP0023` to `OLD`.

Comment: [CMP0023](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/policy/CMP0023.html) has been introduced in CMake 2.8.12, so your framework is really old. "I do not want to set CMP0023 to OLD." - You have a purely legacy code, and you want to tell CMake: No, it is not a legacy, it is... it is... what is it? Note, that disabling that policy affects only on the *emitting of the warning*. Otherwise, CMake behavior isn't changed. That is, all **errors** remain.

Comment: I did not wanted to et CMP0023 to old, because it might be removed in a future version of CMake. But I guess it is the only correct solution.